# How to use sed to extract the source ip from dmseg?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Ubuntu 16.04
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release

I'd like to grab all the syn flood IPs that show in `dmesg`, place them in a global network ban file and then send an email to the abuse email listed in the whois info. I was thinking of using `awk` to `print` the 8th column but sometimes the source IP is not in the 8th column ...

Here is some of the `dmesg` up to the SRC=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

```
[1800391.224826] ** TELNET ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=223.81.204.168
[1800404.868879] ** DSHIELD ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=31.192.108.125
[1800425.582939] ** DSHIELD ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=77.72.85.8
[1800441.745708] ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=193.29.13.157
[1800442.599621] ** TELNET ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=211.216.76.139
[1800442.763812] ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=211.216.76.139
[1800451.809415] ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=108.178.16.154
[1800463.639690] ** TELNET ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=49.79.191.158
```

and here is my script so far ...

```
#!/bin/bash
#

#- create temp folder
tmp_dir="$(mktemp -d -t 'text.XXXXX' || mktemp -d 2>/dev/null)"
tmp_input1="${tmp_dir}/temp_input1.txt"
tmp_input2="${tmp_dir}/temp_input2.txt"
tmp_input3="${tmp_dir}/temp_input3.txt"
wDir="/scripts/tools/dmesg"
whoisDir="${wDir}/.whois"
globalbanDir="${wDir}/.globalbans"
now=$(date +%F)

#-- change dirs to work area
mkdir -p "${globalbanDir}"/"${now}"
cd "$wDir"

#-- dmesg into a log file
dmesg > "$tmp_input1"

#-- sort + unique + count into logfile
dmesg > "$tmp_input1" && awk '{ print $8 }' "$tmp_input1" | sed 's/^....//' |awk '{print $1}' |sort |uniq -c |sort -n |tail > "$tmp_input2"

#-- awk print 2nd column into log file
awk '{ print $2 }' "$tmp_input2" > "$tmp_input3"
cat "$tmp_input3" > "${globalbanDir}"/"${now}"-banned-ips.txt
cat "$tmp_input3"
```

Now when I run this script, I get a mac address also which I do not want.

```
root@pl /scripts/tools/dmesg # bash .dmesg.sh
     11 77.72.82.23
     13 188.18.152.184
     15 107.170.211.70
     15 118.4.255.64
     15 125.64.94.201
     17 206.189.129.11
     17 94.50.122.190
     21 202.59.181.105
     28 85.93.20.244
    712 a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00
```

Instead of using `awk '{ print $8 }'` to fetch the 8th column, maybe someone can show me how to use `sed` to fetch the all the IPs that follow

**SRC=**

Comment: Try this `sed -r 's/.*SRC=([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/\1/' dmesg`

Comment: @Paul Great reply. I'll save this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It;s not clear what you're actually asking for help with but is this what you're looking for?

```
$ awk -F'=' '{print $NF}' file
223.81.204.168
31.192.108.125
77.72.85.8
193.29.13.157
211.216.76.139
211.216.76.139
108.178.16.154
49.79.191.158

$ sed 's/.*=//' file
223.81.204.168
31.192.108.125
77.72.85.8
193.29.13.157
211.216.76.139
211.216.76.139
108.178.16.154
49.79.191.158
```

The above were run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
[1800391.224826] ** TELNET ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=223.81.204.168
[1800404.868879] ** DSHIELD ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=31.192.108.125
[1800425.582939] ** DSHIELD ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=77.72.85.8
[1800441.745708] ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=193.29.13.157
[1800442.599621] ** TELNET ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=211.216.76.139
[1800442.763812] ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=211.216.76.139
[1800451.809415] ** IN_TCP DROP ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=108.178.16.154
[1800463.639690] ** TELNET ** IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=a4:bf:01:07:c9:66:00:ff:ff:ff:ff:fa:08:00 SRC=49.79.191.158
```

Comment: You're right so I reversed everything to make it more understandable. You did understand what I was after and it works perfectly.